# PDO rowcount returns 0 even if update is successful

Tags: pdo, cassandra

I am using pdo to update a cassandra database and rowCount() returns 0 even if the record is updated (when I go and check with the command line in the db).

How can I see what is wrong?

Thanks,

John.

Comment: Is PDO supposed to give a correct rowCount when used with Cassandra? Because its implementation is database dependent.

Comment: maybe you are right because it works fine with mysql.

Comment: I am facing same problem with cassandra pdo. I am using yacassandrapdo.

Answer (score 0):

If something goes wrong, PDO will throw an exception which will spawn a fatal error, and 500 HTTP status as a result. So - check HTTP status to know if anything went wrong.